# Firebase realtime database auth in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, flutterflow

I'm using Firebase realtime database and flutter to create an app. I am following https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/start. Using the following code:

```
    final firebaseApp = Firebase.app();
    final database = FirebaseDatabase.instanceFor(
        app: firebaseApp,
        databaseURL: 'https://myproject.firebaseio.com/');
```

I can access a document that has `".read": true`. When I try to access a document where `".read": "auth != null"`, I get a permission denied error.

How can I use RTDB with Firebase Auth?

Comment: You can literally use it with 'Firebase Auth'. See the document on https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start. And also see the firebase cli on https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios.

Comment: @BGPark are you saying that if firebase auth is in the environment, it somehow magically picks that up and uses it when making requests? Neither of the links you provide show how to tell the database to include auth in the requests to the database.

Comment: If you use the firebase cli (flutterfire configure, the second link), you can get the 'firebase_options.dart' file to your project. And it has the whole information of your project. And then you have to add it your main function. This will link the RTDB to Auth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase SDKs all work together, so once you sign a user in (for example with [email/password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/password-auth)) to Firebase Authentication the SDK for the Realtime Database will automatically pick that up, pass the information to the server, which then makes it available in the `auth` variable of your security rules.

From the documentation on [how Firebase Authentication works](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth#how_does_it_work):

> After a successful sign in, you can access the user's basic profile information, and you can control the user's access to data stored in other Firebase products.

The easiest way to connect and configure everything is by following the flow in the documentation on [adding Firebase to your Flutter app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup), which uses the `flutterfire` CLI tool that @BGPark also commented on.